# Usage of "At most" at the beginning of sentence

Tags: adverbs, word-order

I wrote:

> **At most**, a handle and a pattern can be defined for every node of the tree. For each node a sub-tree, **which at most equals** the whole DOM-tree, must be revisited; therefore, N is multiplied by N in the formula.

I try to explain the reasons for a formula, I describe the worst case. In the sentence above by "At most" I want to say "the most number of the patterns equals the whole number of nodes of a tree". Did I used "At most" correctly in the right position?

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of

> at most

is understandable.  However,

> At most, a handle and a pattern can be defined for every node of the tree.

is usually expressed

> Every node of the tree can have **at most** one handle and one pattern.

When explaining your formula you may want to use "worst case"

> The sub-tree of each node must be revisited, which in worst cases will be the entire DOM-tree, giving a *worst case scenario* of O(N<sup>2</sup>) in the formula.

since you are trying to describe the time complexity.

Comment: *Every node of the tree can have at most one handle and one pattern*, but this is not my intention, as I mentioned in the question, I wan to say *the number of handles and patterns at most equals to N (the number of nodes)*.

Comment: But maybe your sentence also convey the same.

Comment: "At most, **a** handle and **a** pattern can be defined for every node of the tree" means 1 handle and 1 pattern per node. Is "every node can have **N** handles and **N** patterns" maybe what you want to say? It means nodes to handles or patterns is one-to-many. A sub-tree is different than a handle or a pattern? Just because a node can have a sub-tree does not mean the node has **N** handles or **N** patterns where **N** is the number of nodes in the sub-tree.

Comment: Yes, in average one handle or pattern is defined for some nodes. At most these nodes can be all the nodes. Matching each pattern may lead to traversing a sub tree.

Comment: **At most** should not be at the head of the sentence if, as you say, it goes with *every*.  Peter's suggestion to use "in the worst case" instead of *at most* is spot on. Also, you don't want to use **can** but **will have to be** or **must be**.  In the worst case, a handle and a pattern will have to be identified for every node in the tree.